# drop down menu href link not working on mobile view but working on desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My code does not work on MOBILE VIEW but works on desktop, I have been trying to figure out what went wrong but have come to no solution.

This is my code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      
      <div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
        <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo"><a href="index.php" class="h2 mb-0"><img src="images/logo2small.png" alt="logo"><span class="text-primary">.</span> </a></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-none d-xl-block">
        <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">

          <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
            <li class="has-children">
              <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a  href="./about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">Leadership</a></li>
                <li><a  href="about.html" class="nav-link">Careers</a></li>
               
              </ul>
            </li>     
                             
              <li><a href="contact.php" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php" class="btn btn-secondary">Log in</a></li>
            
          </ul>

        </nav>

      </div>


      <div class="col-6 d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 py-3" style="position: relative; top: 3px;"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle float-right"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Comment: Please could you explain in what way it's not working? If you have any error messages, it would be very useful to include them as part of the question as text (not screenshot)

Comment: The href drop down link when clicked doesnt open the page, no error, it just remain where it is nothing happens

Comment: Is it being covered by something maybe? A transparent div perhaps?

Comment: As @RichardHunter said it could be something as simple as that. I noticed you just included part of the code but that part of the code is missing <header> opening tag.